# PropertyModel: what if it's target model changes?

Tags: wicket

The page has a model,I have done `setDefaultModel()`. I have a label added to the page:

```
Label name=new Label("name", new PropertyModel<String>(getDefaultModel(), "name"));
add(name);
```

Later, the page's model changes. But the property model's target model is still the original page's model.

What can I do to keep the property model updated when the target model changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I advise against using `setDefaultModel()` or `setModel()`, exactly because of this type of problems.

Alternatively you can add another indirection:

```
new Label("name", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "defaultModel.name"));
```

... or with Wicket 8:

```
new Label("name", () -> ((Foo)getDefaultModel()).getName());
```

Comment: new PropertyModel<String>(this, "defaultModelObject.name") works.

Comment: Now I understand. The difference is where the lookup starts. In case of `new PropertyModel<String>(getDefaultModel(),"name"`, the model starts with the target model, which does not changes. In case of `PropertyModel<String>(this, "defaultModelObject.name"), the model starts with the page, and works it way down, and encounters `defaultModel`, which has been changed.